# Jasny bootstrap fileupload image preview error

Tags: ajax, image, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

I'm using Jasny Bootstrap Fileupload and is working for the first submit. The problem: after a first submit working ok, the image preview doesn't work anymore.

Steps to reproduce:
1. Select a photo. The photo is showed (img src="data:image/jpeg;base64... is created inside #fileupload-preview)
2. Submit the form. The photo is uploaded ok
3. Reset the form. No photo is showed.
4. Select a photo. The photo is not showed <= ERROR (nothing inside #fileupload-preview)
5. Submit the form. The photo is uploaded ok

To simulate it with JSFiddle you can:
1. Choose a photo
2. Click 'save'
3. Choose another photo. Error....

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YyNS6/2/)

Relevant jasny fileupload code:

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
     <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
     <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
     <div>
          <span class="btn btn-file">
               <span class="fileupload-new">Choose a photo</span>
               <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
               <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" />
          </span>
          <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"> Delete</a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not in the form reset. This works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/YyNS6/3/. I'm having trouble testing because of cross-domain ajax protection.

Comment: I tested this and it works fine using Chrome or Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tried with Firefox 21 and IE10. Your example is working ok. Mine is working for you? I updated it with your reset at the end of ajax request: http://jsfiddle.net/YyNS6/6/ After submit it doesn't work anymore. It works for you? I think ajax should not affect it, but it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in the reset. Instead the `$.ajaxFileUpload` breaks the widget. You can submit a bug for both the Jasny Bootstrap and ajaxFileUpload library.

However perhaps it's easier to resort to another library to upload the form like http://jquery.malsup.com/form/